# "Copy as Fetch" using selenium/selenium-wire python chrome dev tools

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, seleniumwire

i tried using selenium-wire and python to fetch data from network calls
so far i was able to fetch the url from which i want to fetch data using below code

```
for request in driver.requests:
  if request.response:
    if request.url.startswith("https://example.com"):
      print(request.response)
```

How do I "Copy as fetch" in that network url as shown in screenshot below?

[image: link to the copy as fetch option]

Comment: And what is your question? Have you seen [ask]?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.